# Are there any patterns or useful tricks for memorizing family relationships?

Tags: vocabulary, beginners

I have been trying to memorize the words one at a time and it isn't sticking.

Comment: Any particular ones you are having trouble with?

Comment: 하나하나 다 외우셔야합니다. 저같은 경우는 친척이 거의 없기때문에 한국인인데도 불구하고 친족간 호칭을 어떻게 해야하는지 잘모릅니다.

Comment: here is a table that might be helpful: https://blog.naver.com/243-7080/220815033094

Comment: The Kinship terminology always irks me. It's been years I've first seen the word “`조카`” back in my childhood and it still sounds alien to me. It reminds me of a “`joker`.” A native Korean word that has a letter “`카`” in it? So weird….

Comment: @user17915 Saying just in case, those terms are not _addressing terms_, the ones that someone would use to call another in the same family.

Comment: You know what's funny about this? Not to mention the names (명칭) and the corresponding addressing terms (호칭어) are different, the terminology system itself is complicated as heck that there is even an application that tells you how one's supposed to call another.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually, Korean people do not know well the pattern beyond
사촌(cousin)

> We will focus to relation when I was a child.

Couple is 무(zero)촌. That is, there is no curtain. But parents and
child has 일(one)촌. But we do not use 일촌. We use father (아빠,
아버지) or mother (엄마, 어머니). Similarly, grandfather(할아버지)
or grandmother(할머니) has 이(two)촌.

Consider father's younger brother. me->father -> grandfather->
brother so that we call him **삼(three)촌** (uncle). But if he married,
we use **작은아버지**(small father) (And we call his wife **작은어머니**)

Here we call his child **사(four)촌** (cousin). With respect to age, we
use 사촌 동생, 사촌 누나 and so on.

Consider father's older brother : **큰(big)아버지**.

Consider mother's brother : **외삼촌**. (We call his wife **외숙모**)

Consider father's sister and mother's sister : **고모** (aunt, her husband 고모부) and **이모** (her husband 이모부)

@Here 부 is China character implying man or husband.

> Consider when we married or we are old :

(a) Older sister's husband is 매형 and
 conversely, he call me 처남. Younger sister's husband is 매제.

My wife call my older sister 시누이 and younger sister 아가씨.
 Conversely, my sister call my wife 올캐

(b) My younger brother's wife is 제수씨. Conversely, she call me 아주버님.

My wife call younger
 brother 도련님 (If he married, then it is 서방님). In further he
 call my wife 형수.

> In further, consider wife's family :

Wife's older sister call me 제부 and her husband call me 동서.
 Wife's father and mother are 장인 어른 and 장모님.

Lastly, wife's older brother is 형님 (compare 처남)